# Как написать условие цикла так, чтоб учитывалась дата?

Tags: python, pandas

Как можно написать цикл так, что он применялся к каждому году в массиве? Допустим есть такой массив:

Табл.1

| Начало | Конец | Продолжительность | Сумма |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-10-07 | 2016-10-23 | 16 | -114.3 |
| 2016-11-08 | 2016-11-10 | 3 | 3.5 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-03-15 | 75 | -961.4 |
| 2017-11-11 | 2017-12-31 | 51 | -962.4 |
| 2018-03-17 | 2018-03-29 | 13 | -86.1 |
| 2018-04-02 | 2018-10-06 | 188 | 2287.6 |
| 2019-10-07 | 2018-10-13 | 7 | -18.9 |
| 2019-10-14 | 2019-10-18 | 5 | 4.2 |
| 2020-10-23 | 2020-11-07 | 16 | -114.3 |
| 2020-11-11 | 2020-12-31 | 51 | -962.4 |

Нужно, чтобы суммировались значения в колонке "Сумма" отдельно по каждому году и выводились
Нужно, чтобы в новый массив отдельно по каждому году с такими же заголовками выводилась первая и последняя дата года, продолжительность, и сумма. Чтобы получилось следующее:

Табл.2

| Начало | Конец | Продолжительность | Сумма |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-10-07 | 2016-11-10 | 19 | -110.8 |
| 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | 126 | -1923.8 |
| 2018-03-17 | 2018-10-06 | 201 | 2207,5 |
| 2019-10-07 | 2019-10-18 | 12 | -14,7 |
| 2020-10-23 | 2020-12-31 | 67 | -1076,7 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
agg_funcs = {
  "Начало": "min", 
  "Конец": "max", 
  "Продолжительность": "sum", 
  "Сумма": "sum"
}

res = (df
       .assign(yr=df["Начало"].dt.year)
       .groupby("yr")
       .agg(agg_funcs)
       .reset_index()
       .drop(columns="yr"))
```

Результат:

```
In [133]: res
Out[133]:
      Начало      Конец  Продолжительность   Сумма
0 2016-10-07 2016-11-10                 19  -110.8
1 2017-01-01 2017-12-31                126 -1923.8
2 2018-03-17 2018-10-06                201  2201.5
3 2019-10-07 2019-10-18                 12   -14.7
4 2020-10-23 2020-12-31                 67 -1076.7
```

---

PS для того, чтобы данное решение правильно отрабатывало, столбец `Начало` должен иметь тип данных `datetime`. Если у вас в нем строки - следует сначала преобразовать его в `datetime`:

```
df["Начало"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Начало"], errors="coerce")
```

Comment: Не знаю почему, но у меня не работает...

Comment: @ДмитрийЕмельянов, не работать может по-разному. Какая ошибка?

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: @ДмитрийЕмельянов, дополнил ответ...

Comment: спасибо большое, все хорошо работает для ситуации, которую я описывал сначала. Но в моем случае нужно выделять определенный период в году, вычислить его продолжительность и сумму положительных температур. Я думал, что ваш код можно будет как-то, подстроить под то, что у меня уже есть, но пока не получается

Comment: Нет, StackOverflow так не работает. Нельзя изменять вопросы, на которые уже даны ответы таким образом, что ответ перестаёт быть правильным или не отвечает на __изначально__ сформулированный вопрос. Если у вас возник дополнительный вопрос - откройте новый SO вопрос и приведите в нем уточнённый воспроизводимый пример данных и желаемый результат

Comment: хорошо, так и сделаю. Все равно спасибо вашу помощь